# Change the location of runtime.js, polyfills.js and so on in index.html

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular13

In my `index.html` file I have multiple javascript files that are included in the body tag

```html
<body>
    <div ng-view class="view"></div>
    <script src="legacy/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="legacy/script2.js"></script>
    <script src="legacy/script3.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I build my application angular adds the runtime.js, polyfills.js and so on right before the closing of the body tag.

```html
<body>
    <div ng-view class="view"></div>
    <script src="legacy/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="legacy/script2.js"></script>
    <script src="legacy/script3.js"></script>
    <script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="scripts.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Is there any way I change where they are placed?

I need the output to be:

```html
<body>
    <div ng-view class="view"></div>
    <script src="legacy/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="legacy/script2.js"></script>
    <script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="scripts.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="legacy/script3.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using @angular-builders/custom-webpack by using the following:

in your angular.json change builder to `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` and then set `"indexTransform": "./index-html-transform.ts"`

In the `index-html-transform.ts` you can define custom placement logic so I used the following:

```js
import { TargetOptions } from '@angular-builders/custom-webpack';

export default (_targetOptions: TargetOptions, indexHtml: string) => {
    const start = indexHtml.indexOf('<script src="runtime');
    const end = indexHtml.indexOf('</body>');
    const injectionPositionHtml = '<!-- angular13 -->';

    const scripts = indexHtml.slice(start, end);

    return indexHtml.replace(scripts, '').replace(injectionPositionHtml, scripts);
};
```

now I can place `<!-- angular13 -->` between script2 and 3 and it works as intended!

Comment: Cool trick! Never knew this. Thanks!